# Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade error

Tags: upgrade, dovecot

I have Ubuntu 20.04 root on zfs.

I attempted to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04.

The upgrade mostly completed then aborted due to some issue with dovecot.

I was able to reboot

```
root@mail:/# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
root@mail:/# uname -r
5.15.0-58-generic
```

but the email is not working

```
root@mail:/# service dovecot status
× dovecot.service - Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dovecot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-01-23 13:37:06 NZDT; 5h 6min ago
       Docs: man:dovecot(1)
             https://doc.dovecot.org/
    Process: 607945 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dovecot -F (code=exited, status=89)
   Main PID: 607945 (code=exited, status=89)
        CPU: 39ms

Jan 23 13:37:06 mail.xxxxxxxxxxxx.nz systemd[1]: Starting Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server...
Jan 23 13:37:06 mail.xxxxxxxxxxxx.nz dovecot[607946]: doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf line 407: Unknown setting: metric { event_name
Jan 23 13:37:06 mail.xxxxxxxxxxxx.nz dovecot[607945]: doveconf: Error: managesieve-login: dump-capability process returned 89
Jan 23 13:37:06 mail.xxxxxxxxxxxx.nz dovecot[607945]: doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf line 407: Unknown setting: metric { event_name
Jan 23 13:37:06 mail.xxxxxxxxxxxx.nz systemd[1]: dovecot.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=89/n/a
Jan 23 13:37:06 mail.xxxxxxxxxxxx.nz systemd[1]: dovecot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 23 13:37:06 mail.xxxxxxxxxxxx.nz systemd[1]: Failed to start Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
lines 1-16/16 (END)
```

Lines 406, 407 and 408 from /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf

```
metric imap_command_finished {
    event_name = imap_command_finished
}
```

I tried

```
root@mail:/# dpkg --configure -a
```

No output. I also tried

```
root@mail:/# apt install --reinstall dovecot-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  app-install-data-partner autotools-dev bsdmainutils crda g++-9 gcc-10-base gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0
  gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 gnome-getting-started-docs gnome-screenshot gnustep-make gobjc gobjc-11 gobjc-9 ippusbxd
  libaio1 libamtk-5-0 libamtk-5-common libaom0 libasn1-8-heimdal libboost-date-time1.71.0 libboost-filesystem1.71.0 libboost-iostreams1.71.0
  libboost-locale1.71.0 libboost-thread1.71.0 libbrlapi0.7 libcamel-1.2-62 libcbor0.6 libcdio18 libcmis-0.5-5v5 libcodec2-0.9 libdns-export1109 libdvdnav4
  libdvdread7 libedataserver-1.2-24 libedataserverui-1.2-2 libextutils-pkgconfig-perl libfftw3-double3 libfuse2 libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  libgssapi3-heimdal libgupnp-1.2-0 libhandy-0.0-0 libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal libhogweed5 libhx509-5-heimdal libicu66
  libidn11 libigdgmm11 libisl22 libjs-regenerate libjs-util libjson-c4 libjsoncpp1 libjuh-java libjurt-java libkrb5-26-heimdal libkyotocabinet16v5 liblasso3
  libldap-2.4-2 liblibreoffice-java liblinear4 libllvm12 libmemcached11 libmozjs-68-0 libmpdec2 libneon27-gnutls libnettle7 libnginx-mod-http-geoip
  libntfs-3g883 liboath0 libobjc-11-dev libobjc-9-dev liborcus-0.15-0 libperl5.30 libpgm-5.2-0 libphonenumber7 libpoppler97 libprotobuf17 libpython3.8
  libpython3.8-dev libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib libqpdf26 libraw19 libreadline5 libreoffice-style-tango libridl-java libroken18-heimdal librpm8
  librpmbuild8 librpmio8 librpmsign8 libsane libsnmp35 libstdc++-9-dev libtepl-4-0 libtracker-control-2.0-0 libtracker-miner-2.0-0 libtracker-sparql-2.0-0
  libunoloader-java libvpx6 libwbxml2-0 libwebp6 libwind0-heimdal libwireshark13 libwiretap10 libwmf0.2-7 libwsutil11 libx264-155 libx265-179
  libxmlsec1-openssl libytnef0 libzip5 linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-58 ltrace lua-lpeg ncal ndiff nmap nmap-common node-ajv node-ansi node-ansi-align
  node-anymatch node-array-union node-array-uniq node-asn1 node-assert node-assert-plus node-aws-sign2 node-aws4 node-babel7 node-babel7-runtime
  node-bcrypt-pbkdf node-bl node-bluebird node-boxen node-braces node-browserslist node-builtin-modules node-call-limit node-camelcase node-caniuse-lite
  node-caseless node-ci-info node-cli-boxes node-cliui node-co node-commondir node-concat-map node-concat-stream node-config-chain node-configstore
  node-convert-source-map node-core-js node-cross-spawn node-crypto-random-string node-cyclist node-dashdash node-debbundle-es-to-primitive node-decamelize
  node-deep-equal node-deep-extend node-define-properties node-del node-detect-indent node-detect-newline node-dot-prop node-duplexer3 node-duplexify
  node-ecc-jsbn node-editor node-electron-to-chromium node-errno node-error-ex node-es-abstract node-es6-promise node-esutils node-execa node-extend
  node-extsprintf node-fast-deep-equal node-fill-range node-find-cache-dir node-find-up node-flush-write-stream node-forever-agent node-from2
  node-fs-readdir-recursive node-fs-vacuum node-genfun node-get-caller-file node-getpass node-glob-parent node-globals node-globby node-har-schema
  node-har-validator node-has-symbol-support-x node-has-to-string-tag-x node-http-signature node-ignore node-import-lazy node-invert-kv node-is-arrayish
  node-is-extglob node-is-glob node-is-npm node-is-number node-is-obj node-is-object node-is-path-cwd node-is-path-inside node-is-retry-allowed node-is-stream
  node-isstream node-isurl node-js-tokens node-jsbn node-jsesc node-json-schema node-json-schema-traverse node-json-stable-stringify node-json-stringify-safe
  node-json5 node-jsonify node-jsonstream node-jsprim node-latest-version node-lazy-property node-lcid node-libnpx node-locate-path node-lockfile node-lodash
  node-make-dir node-mem node-merge-stream node-micromatch node-mimic-fn node-mississippi node-normalize-path node-npm-run-path node-number-is-nan
  node-oauth-sign node-object-inspect node-os-locale node-os-tmpdir node-p-finally node-p-is-promise node-p-limit node-p-locate node-p-timeout
  node-package-json node-parallel-transform node-parse-json node-path-dirname node-path-exists node-path-is-inside node-path-type node-performance-now
  node-picocolors node-pify node-pkg-dir node-prepend-http node-proto-list node-prr node-pseudomap node-pumpify node-qs node-qw node-rc node-read-pkg
  node-regenerate node-regenerate-unicode-properties node-regenerator-runtime node-regenerator-transform node-regexpu-core node-registry-auth-token
  node-registry-url node-regjsgen node-regjsparser node-repeat-string node-request node-require-directory node-require-main-filename node-resolve-from
  node-semver-diff node-sha node-shebang-command node-shebang-regex node-slide node-sorted-object node-sshpk node-stream-each node-stream-iterate
  node-stream-shift node-strict-uri-encode node-strip-eof node-strip-json-comments node-term-size node-through node-through2 node-timed-out
  node-to-fast-properties node-to-regex-range node-tunnel-agent node-tweetnacl node-typedarray node-uid-number node-unicode-canonical-property-names-ecmascript
  node-unicode-match-property-ecmascript node-unicode-match-property-value-ecmascript node-unicode-property-aliases-ecmascript node-unique-string node-unpipe
  node-uri-js node-url-parse-lax node-url-to-options node-util node-uuid node-v8flags node-verror node-which-module node-widest-line node-wrap-ansi
  node-xdg-basedir node-xtend node-y18n node-yargs node-yargs-parser perl-modules-5.30 popularity-contest python-cairo python-gobject-2 python-markupsafe
  python-pip-whl python-pysqlite2 python3-bs4 python3-entrypoints python3-html5lib python3-lxml python3-packaging python3-requests-unixsocket
  python3-simplejson python3-soupsieve python3-webencodings python3.8 python3.8-dev python3.8-minimal syslinux syslinux-common syslinux-legacy ure-java vino
  x11proto-xext-dev xul-ext-ubufox
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3,319 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Requesting to save current system state
Successfully saved as "autozsys_06nh4k"
(Reading database ... 279222 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dovecot-core_1%3a2.3.16+dfsg1-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dovecot-core (1:2.3.16+dfsg1-3ubuntu2.1) over (1:2.3.16+dfsg1-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up dovecot-core (1:2.3.16+dfsg1-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Configuration file '/etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-vpopmail.conf.ext' is obsolete. Please remove.
Could not execute systemctl:  at /usr/bin/deb-systemd-invoke line 142.
dovecot.socket is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
ZSys is adding automatic system snapshot to GRUB menu
```

What does "Could not execute systemctl:  at /usr/bin/deb-systemd-invoke line 142" mean?

Is this system repairable?

I did save the current state with zsysctl before the upgrade so potentially I could revert the system to before the upgrade and try the upgrade again if someone could suggest what I could do to stop the same issue re-occurring.

**EDIT**

So I tried the upgrade again but this time when it came to the question about dovecot.conf "do I want to keep the local version currently installed or install the package maintainer's version" I chose "install the package maintainer's version" and the upgrade completed but now network manager is not working:

```
/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
/usr/sbin/NetworkManager: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**EDIT**

I went to another computer and did

```
wget http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb
```

put the file on usb transferred it to the problem computer and did

```
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb
```

that got network manager working.

Comment: I would prefer not to do a full reinstall as there is a lot of work involved in installing and configuring software to get to where I am now. I ended up reverting back to 20.04 which worked flawlessly zfs is amazing. There should be some way of figuring out what went wrong the developers need to know.